# Is there a list to explain what the abbreviations in tex stand for or come from?

Tags: symbols

Is there a list to explain what the abbreviations in tex stand for or come from?

For example, `\mathbf`, comes from these three words math, bold and font.

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't as clear as it might be. It seems that what you would like is a list explaining the meanings of control sequence names, or commands -- which are not abbreviations. Also, you have tagged it `symbols`, and `\mathbf` isn't a symbol.  (Perhaps there isn't a better tag though; I can't think of one.) And "bf" isn't "bold font"; it's "boldface", the traditional name for what is admittedly a bold font; compare `\mathit`, where the "it" indicates "italic". Finally, though, I don't believe there is such a list, because too many commands are defined by too many packages.

Comment: Are you specifically referring to TeX? That TeX possibly is an abbreviation?

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for you comments. I agree with you, `\mathbf `isn't a symbol, and which tag should I put?

Comment: @Werner Actually I have no idea what the canonical name of `bf` in `\mathbf` is. would you please give a hint or a link about this?

Comment: Some people probably interpret it as `b`old `f`ont, but it is more likely `b`old`f`ace.

Comment: I've checked the tag list for possible suitable tags, and found none.  There are nearly 2,000 tags and synonyms, and I didn't look at every page of the list, just for likely possibilities.  These are *not* suitable: `csname`, `naming`, `command`.  I'll keep thinking.